# WikiData SPARQL Query Fails, requires CONTAINS to work

Tags: sparql, wikidata

The query below works when I include the line that uses CONTAINS for the filter, but fails if I simply check if the value (LCASE) is equal to "donald trump" (it is).

Use this line, and it works:

FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?idLabel), "donald trump") ).

Use this line, and it fails:

FILTER(LCASE(?idLabel) = "donald trump") .

The output for the query that WORKS has idLabel = "Donald Trump"

SPARQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?PV WHERE {

  ?id wdt:P106 ?V0. VALUES ?V0 { wd:Q39631  } . 

  OPTIONAL {
        ?id rdfs:label ?idLabel .
        FILTER(LANG(?idLabel) = 'en') .
  } .

    # Filter on Label

    # WORKS:
    FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?idLabel), "donald trump") ).

    # DOES NOT WORK
    #FILTER(LCASE(?idLabel) = "donald trump") .

    # subselect on instance type
    {
       SELECT ?id WHERE {
         ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?PV . VALUES(?PV) {(wd:Q5) } .
       }
    }  .
}
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fid%20%3FidLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%0A%20%20%3Fid%20wdt%3AP106%20%3FV0.%20VALUES%20%3FV0%20%7B%20wd%3AQ39631%20%20%7D%20.%20%0A%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fid%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FidLabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%09FILTER%28LANG%28%3FidLabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%20.%0A%20%20%7D%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Filter%20on%20Label%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20WORKS%3A%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28CONTAINS%28LCASE%28%3FidLabel%29%2C%20%22donald%20trump%22%29%20%29.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20DOES%20NOT%20WORK%0A%20%20%20%20%23FILTER%28LCASE%28%3FidLabel%29%20%3D%20%22donald%20trump%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20subselect%20on%20instance%20type%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fid%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fid%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3FPV%20.%20VALUES%28%3FPV%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ5%29%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20.%0A%7D)

My question is WHY the second option does NOT work ?

(And yes, I'm looking for the surgeon Donald Trump, not that other guy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels in Wikidata have language tags, thus, the label literal is

"Donald Trump"@en

and the string after `LCASE` will be

"donald trump"@en

Indeed `CONTAINS` works here.

You have to use `STR` function to get the lexical form, i.e. just

"Donald Trump"

Solution:

`FILTER(LCASE(STR(?idLabel)) = "donald trump") .`

Comment: You are my phreaking hero !